# An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the ListBuckets operation: S3 API Requests must be made to API port

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, minio

We are using Minio for local testing of S3 AND we have created `docker-compose file` with Minio and our app dependency is as follows:

Docker-Compose File:

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
    volumes:
      - minio_storage:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123
      MINIO_REGION: us-east-1
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    mem_limit: 512m

  populate-minio-data:
    container_name: "minio-data"
    image: minio/mc
    volumes:
      - ./hello.txt:/tmp/hello.txt
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      /usr/bin/mc config host rm local;
      /usr/bin/mc config host add --quiet --api s3v4 local http://minio:9001 minio minio123;
      /usr/bin/mc mb --quiet local/somebucketname1/;
      /usr/bin/mc policy set public local/somebucketname1;
      /usr/bin/mc cp /tmp/hello.txt local/somebucketname1/hello.txt;
      "
    depends_on:
      - minio


  archive-api-app:
    image: openjdk:11
    container_name: "archive-api-app"
    ports:
      - 8091:6001
    volumes:
      - /home/apcuser/dev/projects/ea-archive-service-v2/projects/application/archive-api:/app
    command: [ 'java', '-jar', '/app/build/libs/archive-api-1.0.0.jar' ]
    env_file:
      - ./vars/default.env

volumes:
  minio_storage:
```

And In java code, I have configured **MINIO URL as S3 Endpoint** as follows:

```
 @Bean
    public AmazonS3 getS3Client() {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration().withMaxConnections(maxConnections)
                        .withConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout).withMaxErrorRetry(maxRetry))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://minio:9001", "us-east-1"))
                .build();
    }
```

Once, I run `docker-compose file`,I am able to see `minio-ui` in my local Linux machine as follows:

[image]

But I am not seeing any data in Minio, instead, I am seeing the below error while uploading data in minio:

```
Attaching to minio-data
minio-data             | Removed `local` successfully.
minio-data             | Added `local` successfully.
minio-data             | mc: <ERROR> Unable to make bucket `local/somebucketname1/`. S3 API Requests must be made to API port.
minio-data             | mc: <ERROR> Unable to set policy `public` for `local/somebucketname1`. S3 API Requests must be made to API port.
minio-data             | `/tmp/hello.txt` -> `local/somebucketname1/hello.txt`
minio-data             | mc: <ERROR> Failed to copy `/tmp/hello.txt`. S3 API Requests must be made to API port.
minio-data             | Total: 0 B, Transferred: 0 B, Speed: 0 B/s
```

Even same error I am seeing When I am trying to list MINIO data from my local linux host machine:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=minio
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=minio123
export AWS_REGION=us-east-1

aws --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:9001 s3 ls

**An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the ListBuckets operation: S3 API Requests must be made to API port.**
```

Can anyone help here, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message indicates that you need to use the API port instead of console port while using mc.

```
/usr/bin/mc config host add --quiet --api s3v4 local http://minio:9001 minio minio123;
```

You need to use port 9000 instead of 9001.